# Eclipse RCP - remove context menu entry 'Input Methods'

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a Eclipse RCP app. The main editor a a GMF diagram. When I do a right click on the diagram, I get a context menu that has a entry 'Input Methods'. This entry itself has sub-menu-entries.

I need to remove that 'Input Methods' menu entry. Does anyone know how to do that?
I can't find the id of that entry.

(Update: It turned out that this context menu entry only appears on linux (tested with Ubuntu 10.04). It does not appear under Windows XP and MacOs (not sure of the version))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a forum entry, that tells how to remove the 'Input Methods' context menu entry.
This works only for linux, but the entry seems to appear on linux only also.

http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg20408.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a internal setting "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.composite.NO_INPUT_METHOD" can control. 
You can set it after display created.

```
display.setData("org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.noInputMethod",true);
```